# Right Aligned Navigation Bar will automatically jumps down when it doesn't fit

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to do a Right Aligned Navigation Bar with a searchbar and a loginicon to fit the page but I just can't seem to get it do that. It will automatically jumps down which is not my expectation. I want it like in one row.

[Here is my website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDPI5.png)

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}

form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

form input {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.right{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.searchbar{
    margin-right: auto;
}

a.login-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
}

img.login-icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
img.logo {
    width: 230px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;

}
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="index.php"><img class="logo"src="Snooker Logo.png" alt="Logo"></a></li>        
              <li><a href="index.php"><h4>Home</h4></li></a>
              <li><a href="bookingstatus"><h4>Booking Status</h4></li></a>                                
              <li><a href="paymentfile"><h4>Payment</h4></li></a>
              <li><a href="bookingfile"><h4>Booking</h4></li></a>             
          </ul>
          <div class="right">
              <div class="searchbar">
                  <form> 
                      <input type="search" placeholder="Search an event u want">
                  </form>
              </div>
              <a class="login-link" href="#login">
                  <img class="login-icon" src="loginiconsnew.png" alt="Login">
              </a>
          </div>
      </nav>
  </div>
```

I want it like in one row and the searchbar and the loginicon are in right hand side.

Comment: Your provided code does not demonstrate the issue, please clarify.

Answer (score -1):

```
nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
    }

    ul {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul li {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    form {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 20px;
    }

    form input {
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .right {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .searchbar {
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    a.login-link {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    img.login-icon {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    img.logo {
        width: 230px;
        height: auto;
        margin-right: 20px;

    }
```

Use the above CSS where I remove the float, and it works correctly as you need it on my PC.

[image: output]